# Unable to connect to PgBouncer admin console

Tags: database, postgresql, connection-pooling, pgbouncer

I'm unable to connect to my PgBouncer admin console. Below is my `pgbouncer.ini` configuration.

```
################## Auto generated ##################
[databases]
* = host=postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local port=5432 user=someuser

[pgbouncer]
listen_addr = 0.0.0.0
listen_port = 5432
unix_socket_dir =
user = postgres
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
auth_type = md5
pool_mode = transaction
max_client_conn = 3000
default_pool_size = 50
min_pool_size = 10
reserve_pool_size = 10
reserve_pool_timeout = 5
max_db_connections = 50
max_user_connections = 50
ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits

# Log settings
admin_users = postgres

# Connection sanity checks, timeouts
server_reset_query = DISCARD ALL
server_idle_timeout = 100

# TLS settings

# Dangerous timeouts
################## end file ##################
```

I have a `userlist.txt` file which contains

```
"someuser" "password"
```

I have tried connecting to the admin console using `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U someuser -d pgbouncer`, but get thrown with this error

```
psql: ERROR: not allowed
```

I have also tried connecting using `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d pgbouncer`, but `psql`throws

```
psql: ERROR: no such user: postgres
```

FYI, I'm using `edoburu/pgbouncer:1.9.0` Docker image.

Answer (score 3):

Since you seem to be connecting from the same machine that pgbouncer is running on, I would try connecting via a Unix socket:

- Step 1: Set `unix_socket_dir=/tmp` in `pgbouncer.ini`. [See docs for details](https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html)
- Step 2: Connect using the Unix socket with user `pgbouncer` and no password:

```
$ psql --host=/tmp --username=pgbouncer --no-password pgbouncer

psql (12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1), server 1.8.1/bouncer)
Type "help" for help.

pgbouncer=#
```

### Why this works

According to the [pgbouncer-docs](https://www.pgbouncer.org/usage.html), this will let you connect locally without a password:

> Additionally, the user name **pgbouncer** is allowed to log in without password, if the login comes **via the Unix socket** and the client has **same Unix user UID** as the running process.

(My emphasis.)

Comment: Thanks for the emphasis on "same Unix user UID", i had to change user with `sudo su postgres` because my pgbouncer service was run as `postgres` user.